# Automated web deployment on multiple servers with Mercurial

Tags: deployment, mercurial

I've been looking at some workflows for Mercurial recently, as we start using it for our web development. We need an automated way to propagate changes that are pushed to the testing and live instances to multiple endpoints. Here's a diagram of the idea:

```
         +-------+
         |Dev    |
         |       |
         +-------+
             |  Push
             +--------+
                      |
                      V
+-------+   Push  +-------+
|Live   |<--------|Test   |
|server |         |server |
+-------+         +-------+
    |    +-------+    |    +-------+
    +--->|Live 1 |    +--->|Test 1 |
    |    |       |    |    |       |
    |    +-------+    |    +-------+
    |                 |
    |    +-------+    |    +-------+
    +--->|Live 2 |    +--->|Test 2 |
    |    |       |    |    |       |
    |    +-------+    |    +-------+
    |                 |
    |    +-------+    |    +-------+
    +--->|Live 3 |    +--->|Test 3 |
         |       |         |       |
         +-------+         +-------+
```

Basically, the idea is that all that we as the developers would have to do is, once the development has reached a stable level, to issue the push command (which doesn't necessarily have to just be a `hg push`) to the test server, and from there it would automatically propagate out. Then, once testing is done, we'd push it from test to live (or, if it would be easier, we could push from dev to live), and that would also propagate out to each of the different instances.

It would be nice if we could add new test and live instances fairly easily (e.g. maybe if the IPs were stored in a database that could be read by a script, etc...).

What would be the best way to accomplish this? I know about Mercurial hooks. Maybe an in-process script that the hook would run? I've also looked into [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/index.html), would that be a good option?

Also, what kind of support software would each of the endpoints need? Would it be easiest if a Mercurial repository existed on each server? Would SSH access be beneficial? Etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done something like this using Mercurial, [Fabric](http://fabfile.org), and [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/):

```
   +-------+
   | Devs  |
   +-------+
       | hg push
       V
   +-------+
   |  hg   |  "central" (by convention) hg repo
   +-------+\
    |        \
    |         +--------------+
    | Jenkins job            | Jenkins job
    | pull stable            | pulls test
    | branch & compile       | branch & compile
    |       +-------+        |
    |  +----|Jenkins|-----+  |
    |  |    +-------+     |  |
    V  |                  |  V
   +-------+          +-------+
   | "live"|          | "test"|  shared workspaces ("live", "test")
   +-------+          +-------+
     | Jenkins job         | Jenkins job     <-- jobs triggered
     | calls fabric        | calls fabric        manually in
     |    +-------+        |    +-------+        Jenkins UI
     |--> | live1 |        |--> | test1 |
 ssh |    +-------+    ssh |    +-------+
     |    +-------+        |    +-------+
     |--> | live2 |        |--> | test2 |
     |    +-------+        |    +-------+
     |    ...              |    ...
     |    +-------+        |    +-------+
     +--> | liveN |        +--> | testN |
          +-------+             +-------+
```

- I don't have a repo on each web server; I use fabric to deploy only what is necessary.
- I have a single fabfile.py (in the repo) that contains all the deploy logic
- The set of servers (IPs) to deploy to is given as a command line arg to fabric (it's part of the Jenkins job config)
- I use Jenkins shared workspaces so I can separate the tasks of pulling and compiling from actually deploying (so I can re-deploy the same code if necessary)
- If you can get away with a single Jenkins job that pulls-compiles-deploys, you'll be happier.  The shared workspaces thing is a hack I have to use for my setup, and has downsides.

To directly address some of your questions:

- Devs working on the test branch can push at their leisure, and collectively decide when to run the Jenkins job to update the test environment
- When test is happy, merge it to stable and run the Jenkins job to update the live environment
- Adding a new web box is just a matter of adding another IP to the command line used to invoke fabric (i.e. in the config for the Jenkins job)
- All servers will need ssh access from the Jenkins box

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Jenkins, I hadn't known about it. In any case, it looks like SSH might be the way to go.

Comment: @overthink - very interesting thanks.  What would you say the benefits of using fabric are, over something like make?  Also - passing the IPs via command line params - would that work when you had two sets of IPs (e.g. two types of server)?

Comment: @UpTheCreek I imagine you could do it with make, but fabric is purpose-built for this and has built-in notions of hosts, roles, and running commands on remote boxes over ssh.  So you end up with pretty short task definitions, and not a lot of machinery to maintain.  For multiple server types I use [fabric roles](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/usage/execution.html#roles).