# Push deployment with of node.js application with mercurial

Tags: node.js, deployment, mercurial, express

I've read a few examples of automated deployment of node.js/express applications using Git pushes and hooks.

For example, as documented here: http://catchvar.com/nodejs-server-and-web-sockets-on-amazon-ec2-w

This looks like a good idea, but unfortunately I'm using Mercurial.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for achieving the same thing using mercurial? (and SSH)

Answer (score 2):

Mercurial doesn't support separating working directory from repository directly, but for your purpose you can use something like `hg archive files ~/www` in a `changegroup` [hook](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook).

Answer (score 0):

I think this question has a solution which may be close to what you are looking for even if a little tricky. Otherwise i would appreciate knowing how you solved the issue if you were able to?

[Automated web deployment on multiple servers with Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348070/automated-web-deployment-on-multiple-servers-with-mercurial)

Comment: I'm still evaluating the solution provided by @cababunga - I don't have anything better than that.  I'll post back once I've settled on something.